# How to enter LinkedHashMap Values to database without using bean?

Tags: java, dictionary, linkedhashmap

I am new to LinkedHashMap.

Now I have some data with a LinkedHashMap like-

```
article_ID=386247568292, author_externalId=235697849816687, author_fbid=235697849816687, ...
```

Now here is my code for db entry

```
public void InsertEntry(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> entMap) throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    conn = pool.getConnection();
    String sql="INSERT into socialmedia(article_ID,author_externalId, author_fbid)"
                + "VALUES(?,?,?)";
   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Now how could I enter My LinkedHashMap values to the string so that I can enter all those to database.

I did not want to use any Bean.

Answer (score 1):

### Get the values from LinkedHashMap

```
// either you loop thru the entries
Set<String> keys = entMap.keySet();
int param = 1;
for(String k:keys) {
    pstmt.setString( (param++), (String)entMap.get(k) );
}

or

// if you prefer use the key names, e.g.
String aid = (String) entMap.get("article_ID");
```

### About the LinkedHashMap

- Remember that you will get values from the LinkedHashMap in **order in which the entries were put**.
- You will have to be sure that they **always are put in that order**.
- A solution could be that you check the key (by name) and determine if it is the order/type you expect, to make your solution more solid. And make sure that the values will be treated by setString, setInt etc.

### SQL IN parameters

- Keep in mind that setString will handle all your inserts as String objects. This will work for most of jdbc supported db. But it is not 100% to be comfort on. If you know you have Integers etc, then handle them as setInt.

From **[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)** specification:

> The setter methods (`setShort`, `setString`, and so on) for setting IN parameter values **must** specify types that are compatible with the defined SQL type of the input parameter. **For instance, if the IN parameter has SQL type INTEGER, then the method `setInt` should be used.**

Now this is maybe not so strict in all database servers/jdbc drivers but worth to mention if your inserts fails.

Answer (score 0):

below should work....

```
public void InsertEntry(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> entMap) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    conn = pool.getConnection();
    String sql="INSERT into socialmedia(user_name,article_count,epoch,description,authorId,article_url,publish_date,harvest_date,following,followers,updates,sentiment)"
            + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    Set keys = entmap.keySet();  
    int rowId=1;
    for(String key : keys)
    {
       String val = entMap.get(key);
       pstmt.setString(rowId,val);
       rowId++;
    }
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The map has String key in it... so the LinkedHashMap should have all string keys in it.. as per the parameterized Map provided in the question

Comment: might be... we can do that.. as conceptually rowId varaible is representing columns within the INSERT query

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for your responses. I did it like-

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO students(article_ID, description_charset, author_appScopedId, author_externalId) values(?,?,?,?);
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pstmt.setString(1, (String) entMap.get("article_ID"));
pstmt.setString(2, (String) entMap.get("description_charset"));
pstmt.setString(3, (String) entMap.get("author_appScopedId"));
pstmt.setString(4, (String) entMap.get("author_externalId"));

pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Good, I would also get them by key. As I wrote, this will give you a more solid solution as you know what you get (type), in what order and what you insert into your table.